# How to Link two IDs from different classes in MVC5 to display certain information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to link up the **RestaurantId** in the **RestaurantReservationEventsTbl** with the **RestaurantID** in the **RestaurantTbl** to display reservations that are only made for the currently logged in restaurant.

I am receiving the following error in my code *operator == cannot be applied to operands of type int and iqueryable int*

Here is what I am doing in my home controller

```
var RestaurantIDRestaurantTbl = from r in db.Restaurants select r.RestaurantID;
//var listOfRestaurantsReservations = db.RestaurantReservationEvents.ToList();
var listOfRestaurantsReservations = db.RestaurantReservationEvents.Where(x => x.RestaurantID == RestaurantIDRestaurantTbl).ToList();
//return View(restaurants.Where(x => x.RestaurantEmailAddress == UserEmail).ToList());
//create partial view called _RestaurantReservation
return PartialView("_RestaurantReservations", listOfRestaurantsReservations);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code to materialize the `restaurantIds` like this:

```
var RestaurantIDRestaurantTbl = (from r in db.Restaurants
                                 select r.RestaurantID).ToList();
```

Then you may change the code as below for the comparison to work:

```
 var listOfRestaurantsReservations = db.RestaurantReservationEvents.Where(x => RestaurantIDRestaurantTbl.Contains(x.RestaurantID)).ToList();
```

Anyway this is not the best solution. I will write another example for you, just try this example if it is working or not and let me know for the result.

I would considering changing the code as below to be much more efficient:

```
var listOfRestaurantsReservations = (from r in db.Restaurants
                                    join e in  db.RestaurantReservationEvents 
                                    on r.RestaurantID equals e.RestaurantID
                                    //where r.RestaurantID == something //if where condition needed
                                    select e).ToList();
```

If your tables are not connected with foreignkeys please consider to read this documentation [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) to make a better structure of the tables since they are related to each-other.

If your tables are related as in documentation article you might have something like that:

```
var RestaurantIDRestaurantTbl = db.Restaurants.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RestaurantID == something);
if(RestaurantIDRestaurantTbl != null)
{
   var listOfRestaurantsReservations = RestaurantIDRestaurantTbl.RestaurantReservationEvents.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This compiles correctly but does not work I am still shown reservations which do not correspond with the logged in restaurant

Comment: I think the problem is here that I am not obtaining the correct Restaurant ID of the logged in user so the comparison does not work correctly

Comment: hmm this might be the problem, set a dummy id that exists in database and debug the expression if it bring some data. If it brings some data thats the problem. Anyway try the second way because it is much better since it will generate only one query and brings only neccessery data in application

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    // This will give you a list of IDs
    var RestaurantIDRestaurantTbl = db.Restaurants
        .Select(p => p.RestaurantID)
        .ToList();

    // Using .Any() is a better choice instead of .Contains()
    // .Contains is used to check if a list contains an item while .Any will look for an item in a list with a specific ID
    var listOfRestaurantsReservations = db.RestaurantReservationEvents
        .Where(p => RestaurantIDRestaurantTbl.Any(r => r.pRestaurantID == p))
        .ToList();
}
```